# Fancy chapter header

Tags: sectioning, chapters, report

I want to make a special chapter header, with the following format:

[image]

So far, the closest thing I got is this:

[image]

My MWE is:

```
\documentclass[12p]{report}
\usepackage{arabtex}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T2A,LAE,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{utf8}
\setcode{utf8}
\usepackage{ae}
\usepackage{aecompl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{fancybox}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{bbding}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{csquotes} 
 \usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage{tikz, blindtext}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\definecolor{myblue}{RGB}{100,127,255}

\usepackage{titlesec}

\makeatletter
\def\thickhrulefill{\leavevmode \leaders \hrule height 1ex \hfill \kern \z@}
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
\vspace*{10\p@}%
{\parindent \z@ \centering \reset@font
    \thickhrulefill
    \par\nobreak
    \scshape \@chapapp{} \strut\thechapter
    \par\nobreak
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \hrule
    \vspace*{10\p@}%
    {\Huge \bfseries #1}\par\nobreak
    \thickhrulefill
    \vspace*{10\p@}%
 \vskip 100\p@
  }}
 \def\@makeschapterhead#1{%
 \vspace*{10\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@ \centering \reset@font
    \thickhrulefill
    \par\nobreak
    {\Huge \bfseries \strut #1}\par\nobreak
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \hrule
    \vspace*{10\p@}%
\vskip 100\p@
 }}


\begin{document}

\chapter{Présentation du projet \\ Dans ce chapitre nous allons présenter le 
cadre général du projet, les problèmes affrontés et les études effectuées 
pour les résoudres}

 \lipsum[1-15]

 \chapter{Two}

 \lipsum[1-15]

 \end{document}
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: You want the fleurons  and ornaments too?  This will be a chapter  with more-than-oriental splendour…

Comment: Hahaha, yes I do. But I already have those as png images :)

Comment: I'd suggest  to define the small text after  the chapter title as an environment somewhat similar to `abstract`. It would be easier to do. Also for a standard class like report, you should use the  canonical package for this job – `titlesec`.

Comment: Do not use package ``ae/aecompl``:  it is obsolete from more than 10 years. Use  instead``lmoderb`` (at least for European character test) .
Babel 's``frenchb`` is also obsolete and bust be replaced by ``french``